# Codeigniter bootstrap for PHP CLI

Tags: codeigniter, php

I am developing a PHP CLI tool, which I want to bootstrap with CodeIgniter to be able to use some of it's libraries, like database and accessing configuration.

So basically I want to have a CLI script, that would allow me to load up the CodeIgniter environment and then do `$CI->db->stuff()`.

I know that I could create a controller for this but I am looking for a way to make it CodeIgniter-installation-independent, so that I could simply `$ cd` into a dir, load it's CI environment and perform magic via command line. Another reason why I don't want to use a controller is that I don't want it to be accessible to public via address bar.

So, any ideas?

Comment: Maybe a bit off topic, but [FuelPHP](http://docs.fuelphp.com/index.html) comes with an interactive CLI similar to Rails called [Oil](http://docs.fuelphp.com/packages/oil/intro.html). If you're just starting a new project, you might consider trying it out ;)

Comment: Pretty amazing, never heard of it but it looks promising. Oil is something similar I want to make for myself to use in CodeIgniter.

Comment: :) Check out [Introduction to Scaffolding With Oil](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2011/03/fuelphp-oil-introduction-scaffolding)

Comment: Why don't you redirect the controller with `routes.php`. In this way, your controller would be redirected to the path that you want and it would not be accessible to the people no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command line capabilities are baked into the latest version now. Enjoy:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html

Comment: I was doing some more research on CI CLI and actually have found [this small library](https://bitbucket.org/caseyamcl/snippets/src/b8907d9086f7/ci-cli/), which provides a sandbox for command line so I think I will use a combination of it + default CI behavior for CLI. Thanks!